# I want to paste the rows for the items in Sheet1 Table 1 that are not in Sheet2 Table 2 into Sheet3 with vba

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

So basically I have a list of products in Table 1, Column 1 in Sheet1, I also have an updated list in Table 2, Column 1 in Sheet2. I want to be able to see what new products have been added and paste their respective rows from sheet 2 into blank sheet 3. (So basically paste whatever isn't in Sheet1 but is in Sheet 2 into a new sheet.

I tried using the Vlookup application function within my code but it's not working out so well. When I run the macro, nothing happens.
 Any help would be appreciated!

```
Sub try()
Dim Last1 As Long
Dim colPartNum As Integer

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NewV")
Last1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
colPartNum = .Range("Table2[PART NUMBER]").Column


For p = Last1 To 1 Step -1
On Error Resume Next
    If .Cells(p, colPartNum) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("Table2[PART NUMBER]", "Table1[PART NUMBER]", 1, False).Value _
    Then .Cells(p, "A").EntireRow.Copy
Worksheets("AddedParts").Range("A1").EndxlDown.Offset(1, 0).Paste
Next p
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: which line are you getting the error?

Comment: well when vlookup doesn't find a match it gives me an error. so what I tried to do was if that error occurs with that cell value to copy the cell to the new sheet.

Answer (score 0):

`Range` doesn't include a `Paste` method. Use `PasteSpecial` instead or, better yet, copy and paste in one statement using the optional `Destination` parameter of this method.

Comment: neither of them worked so it must be another issue in the code